# Webserver to trigger ssh shell script

Tags: php, linux, shell, ssh, eventtrigger

I have googled this a lot but none of the results I have found worked for me. So far, I have only tried to do this with php, but cgi, javascript or whatever works is fine with me, as long as it gets the job done.

I would like to access a certain URL on my debian webserver. Once opened in the browser, this file shall execute the following shell commands. No buttons or links. If possible, I'd like to just open the URL, then have the script being started.

```
    ssh user@192.168.189.12 <<'ENDSSH'
    osascript ~/Desktop/Scripts/script.scpt
```

When running this as a regular .sh file it works fine. I have created lockkeys so that no password is prompted when connecting from A to B. What can I do to trigger this from, for example, the browser on my smartphone?

I am *not* trying to connect directly from any device to the Mac containing script.scpt. It is essential that the debian server triggers it and that it is executed by the webserver.

I just started learning about terminal comments, scripts and so on, so I have very basic knowledge of the subject. Please be patient with me.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You can use exec in PHP (or any scripting language) to execute a command line program. You will want to execute the SSH command. Then, you can add a command for SSH to run. It would look like: exec('ssh user@192.168.189.12 oascript ~/Desktop/Scripts/script.scpt'); Of course, this will require you to use ssh keys for login instead of a password.

Answer (score 0):

for simplicity I prefer to create a bash script.  Let's call it

/var/NONwebroot/sshcoolstuff.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
  ssh user@192.168.189.12 <<'ENDSSH'
  osascript ~/Desktop/Scripts/script.scpt
```

make sure it is executable

```
<?php

exec('/var/NONWwebroot/sshcoolstuff.sh');

?>
```

Now I'd recommend putting some protection on that PHP script.  Either limit who has access to it by IP address, or a password, or both.

here is a test bash script for you

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > test << EOF
Hello World!
This is my test text file.

You
can also
have
a whole lot
more text and
lines
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but no success. Do I need to modify user accounts for this to work? I have been told that apache most likely runs as user www-data, therefore has no home directory (and ssh-id) and cannot identify.
I am going to try whether or not different scripts (that do not require home access) will work with this bash script.

Comment: So I have created a different test bash script. 
php.sh
`#!/bin/bash
zenitfy --info --text="This is a test."
sudo chmod +x php.sh`

Then created trigger.php 
`<?php
exec('/var/scripts/php.sh');
?>`
sudo chmod 660 trigger.php

Nothing happens when I open the php-file.

Comment: Does it give any errors ?  Are you sure Apache has rights to execute the script in that location ?  I'd start with putting the file to the same folder as the php script and make it owned by your Apache user. Have it do something like cat >> file.txt. Something you know that php is allowed to do already

Comment: For testing I have created `date > #!/bin/bash 
cat >> file.txt
end` as php.ssh in the same directory trigger.php is in (/var/www). trigger.php -> `<?php exec('php.sh'); ?>` Nothing happens when I open the php file in my browser.

Comment: Sorry I was typing from a phone @bnjrmn .  Make your bash script like this.  


`#!/bin/sh
cat > test << EOF
Hello World!
This is my test text file.

You
can also
have
a whole lot
more text and
lines
EOF`

added to my post above because of the line breaks

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but this does not work for me either. Maybe I have an error in my php server configuration... As for now, I have found a different solution. I send a command to a certain port to my webserver via browser, then trigger shell scripts according to the command. Still need to improve the script, but it works for now.